# Convert one field differently using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I received the following JSON:

```
{ id: 5, users: [{ id: 23523 }, { id: 75743}] }
```

Now to map this probably I would need the class

```
public class Domain {
    int id;
    List<User> users;
}
```

But I actually just want to store the id's:

```
public class Domain {
    int id;
    List<Integer> users;
}
```

Do I really have to implement a whole custom converter in this?

Comment: Custom deserializer for Gson will solve your problem.

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev Granted, but the Deserializer expects a specific class, which is not the case with List<Integers>, is it?

Comment: You can write a deserializer for `Domain`, not for `List<Integer>`. It's a little extra work, but taking complexity of your JSON it's not a problem